# Total number of outcomes for placing 8 rooks on a chessboard: Combination or Permutation?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm puzzled about how to count the total number of cases/outcomes for placing 8 rooks on a chessboard. I thought it should be n choose k, thus $\binom{ 64 }{ 8 }$.

But, I found its answer is ${}_{64} \mathrm{ P }_8$. Why is it Permutation? i.e. why the order of the 8 rooks matters?

Comment: If the rooks are indistinguishable, then you have $64$ choices for the first rook, then $63$ for the next one, $62$ for the next, etc., until you have placed $8$ of them. This is $64\times 63\times...\times 57$ which is $64\text{P}8$.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct for the number of choices of the $8$ squares from $64$ where the rooks are to be placed.